# Facebook Graph API version not supported

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I want to access a facebook page data, and my fb Graph API version is **3.1**, when i am writting this(in python):

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version = 3.1)
```

it gives a version error, i.e:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: Valid API versions are '2.7', '2.8', '2.9', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12', '3.0'
```

how can i access facebook Graph API through my version in python.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if there is an update of whatever SDK you are using there available?

Comment: yes im using facebook-sdk library in python, and it is not supporting Graph API version 3.1

Comment: Well then you will either have to use an app id that still allows you to use a lower API version, or wait for an update of the library, or check where the library does this check and manually add 3.1 to the list there.

Comment: If this is the lib you are taking about, then you should be able to simply add it in the list here: https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/8aad7fce8ca539e6d4113020a5024df68535ecdf/facebook/__init__.py#L49

Comment: You could answer it below and i will check it as answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either

- have to use an app id that still allows you to use a lower API version, or
- wait for an update of the library, or
- see where the library does this check and manually add 3.1 to the list there.

If you are using this library https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/, you can edit the `__init__.py` file, which currently contains the following line:

```
VALID_API_VERSIONS = ["2.7", "2.8", "2.9", "2.10", "2.11", "2.12", "3.0"]
```

If you add `"3.1"` to that list, you should be able to use API version 3.1 without getting this error.